# How do I create a QtWidgets ListView equivalent in Qt Quick Controls?

Tags: qt, qml

This question is a little specific, but I've been unable to find someone with the same problem or a clean solution to the problem.

I'm creating a Qt Quick program, and I want to use a QListView as it appears in QtWidgets. [This QtWidgets program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vtXS.png) has three such views, with checkable items (which is optional: not all QListViews have checkable items).

Because Qt Quick Components doesn't appear to have a QListView equivalent, I set out to make my own from existing components. And the result is ... meh. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjG3i.png) and doesn't exactly behave in the same fashion. Clicking on the text/whitespace of an item *checks* the item, instead of highlighting it. And the border is just ugly, and doesn't appear in GTK-themed environments. It also doesn't obey custom  desktop themes, because the background of the items will *always* be white.

The code for this custom component is fairly brief, and looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

// GroupBox creates a border... most of the time. Not in GTK envs
GroupBox {
    id: root
    property var model: null

    // This wraps the ListView up with a scrollbar
    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListView {  // This is the view component
            anchors.fill: parent

            model: root.model

            // This is the white box that the CheckBox is drawn on
            delegate: Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: box.height

                // This is the actual item
                CheckBox {
                    id: box
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    text: thing  // `thing` is just a placeholder value from the model
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see which border exactly is the problem. On the screenshot it is okay, isn't it?

Comment: It's the border around the ListView. [This magnified image](http://i.imgur.com/kP5sDGl.png) should show it quite nicely. The window on the left is the QtWidgets QListView. The window on the right is my own ListView contraption.

Comment: The white background is due to the usage of `Rectangle` as the top item of the `delegate`. Just use `Item` to have transparent background or set `color: transparent` in the current code - the first approach is better. Also the `CheckBox` should not fill the delegate so that a `MouseArea` can be used to set `currentIndex` and thus move the `highlight` component to the current selected `CheckBox`. These changes should really improve the overall look & feel. Unfortunately, I think that obtaining a perfect theming would be quite trick and probably impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `QApplication` instead of a `QGuiApplication`. It will require you to add widgets support (and ship Qt widgets libs). This way, Qt Quick Components will automatically get access to much more system theming like background color in text selection.

Additionally, [SystemPalette](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-systempalette.html) will provide you with a bunch of native colors that you can use if you want.

Unsatisfying system integration using `QGuiApplication`:
[image: system integration using QGuiApplication]

Nice integration using `QApplication`:
[image: integration using QApplication]

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been using `qmlscene` to prototype this, and intend to launch it from PyQt (or regular C++, if you will) later on. How would using `QApplication` for a Qt Quick application allow me to leverage better system integration? I don't quite see the connection.

Comment: I added screenshots of the difference I mentioned. In my case `qmlscene` renders the app nicely like `QApplication`. So maybe you already get the better of both results. You might want to go for `SystemPalette` to tweak the UI.

Comment: Oh, but that's not really the problem. The problem I'm having is that I want to use a component in Qt Quick that doesn't really exist out of the box. I want to have a ListView inside of QtQuick that looks and behaves similarly to the QListView that exists within QtWidgets. I created my own, kind of, but the border is dodgy and it doesn't obey system themes. The SystemPalette might solve the background colour issue, but I'm uncertain how it'd fix the border issue, unless I defined the border as a line of pixels around the ListView.